# Where is vcbuild in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, locate, vcbuild

I've upgraded to VS2010 and am looking for the vbuild executable. For VS2008, it was under:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\vcbuild.exe

Where is it for VS2010? It's not under:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcpackages\vcbuild.exe

Comment: Hehe, they worked quite hard on eliminating it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There isn't a vcbuild anymore - it's [replaced by msbuild](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/01/11/vcbuild-vs-c-msbuild-on-the-command-line.aspx)

There is also a `TFSBuild.exe` in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE` but I don't know if it's an exact replacement.

Answer (score 13):

I was running into a similar issue with a Node.js module refusing to install unless I added the location of `vcbuild.exe` to the system path.

[@neslekkiM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3308/neslekkim)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19949785/2696690) was a starting point for me, but I didn't want to have to install the entire Visual Studio or SDK - I just wanted the build tools. I ended up finding out you can download the build tools by themselves:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159

Once installed, your `vcbuild.exe` should be located somewhere in the subfolders of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin` (mine was in amd64).

I know this question is a few years old, but hopefully this helps someone later down the road.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me, but not all the way.  I went to the link and only found **Microsoft Build Tools 2013**, which created a `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin` folder but no `VCBuild.exe`.

But another SO [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat#comment30518746_10558328) which pointed me to [http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=7729279](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=7729279) which was a download of **VC++ 2008 Express Edition** which installed `VCBuild.exe` at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages`

Comment: The Build Tools link has changed, but Visual Studio 2015 Build Tools are located at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159 - this allows me to proceed with compiling the node script into a single binary with nexe.

Answer (score 2):

Installing Windows SDK 7 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138 gives you back vcbuild
But that revealed an new problem for us, ATLMFC is not installed. (needed to build our software on the buildserver, had to install vs2008)

Comment: I have Windows SDK 7.1 and I don't have vcbuild. The one you linked is 7.0. Should I install both in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install) package manager:

```
choco install -y vcbuildtools
```

Answer (score -1):

Install Microsoft Visual C++. Set an environment variable for `VCbuild.exe` to the Visual Studio folder.