# error MSB3411: Could not l oad the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, node-gyp

I have Visual Studio 2010 with SP1 and Windows sdk 7.1.
I also have VS2012 and Windows kit 8.

when i run `Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt` and run `node-gyp build --msvs_version=2010` it gives me error:

```
error MSB3411: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". 
If the component is not installed,
either 1) install the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Fr
amework 3.5, or 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.
```

Is it trying to find VCBuild.exe.

I found that [vcbuild has been replaced with msbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761395/where-is-vcbuild-in-vs2010).

*Is it a valid error ?*

I also found that in Windows 7, for .NET 3.5, you just need to turn it on from Control Panel. I have looked at other questions on stackoverflow like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380653/msb3411-could-not-load-visual-c-component) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278417/cannot-install-node-modules-that-require-compilation-on-windows-7-x64-vs2012).

But issue is that since vcbuild.exe does not exist in system with vs2010 then why does node-gyp is searching for it ? Or am i missing something ?

*How do i resolve this error ?*

Comment: possible duplicate of [MSB3411 Could not load Visual C++ component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380653/msb3411-could-not-load-visual-c-component)

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278417/cannot-install-node-modules-that-require-compilation-on-windows-7-x64-vs2012 maybe

Comment: the question is that vcbuild.exe  does not exists in visual studio 2010 then why does node-gyp search for it ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The following has worked for me (as of June 2014), as described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22399133/1469621).

- Install free Visual Studio Express 2013 for **Windows** (not VS Express 2013 for Web)
- npm install --msvs_version=2013

Otherwise, I have spent a lot of time installing old Microsoft packages and patches, and it wasn't helpful.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, but Windows 7 x64 requires "Express 2013 for Windows Desktop" instead.
Also `npm config --global set msvs_version 2013` may be useful.

Comment: Anyone got a link for Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows? I can only find one that doesn't work.  And on the VS website, it express for windows says 'coming soon'.  Sooo fed up with VS.

Answer (score 7):

Setting up the VS2010 and other applications as listed at [node-gyp wiki](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/wiki/Visual-Studio-2010-Setup) solved the problems.

On Windows XP/Vista/7, node-gyp requires Python 2.7 and Visual Studio 2010

According to the readme file in Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Service Pack 1 Compiler Update for the Windows SDK 7.1, to ensure that your system has a supported configuration,

**uninstall the following products first** (if you want to save tons of time)

and then **reinstall them in the order** listed: (you can uninstall in any order :P)

```
Visual Studio 2010

Windows SDK 7.1

Visual Studio 2010 SP1

Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Compiler Update for the Windows SDK 7.1
```

On x64 environments, the last update in the list fixes errors about missing compilers and

`error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found`.

Comment: This worked for me; I didn't even have Visual Studio at all when I ran into this problem trying to install Karma (testacular) on my Win7 system.

Comment: @Ashish Negi is Visual Studio 2010 & Visual studio 2010 Professional same?

Comment: I think `VS 2010 express` is free. if you have `professional` it would be good too.

Comment: If using VS Express note that you need the VS Express for Desktop Version. VS Express for Web does not work

Answer (score 6):

The answer to all your question lies [here](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp). Struggled a lot to find this. Finally got it working. =)

Just to save you time visiting the link here is what's useful in that link.

**INSTRUCTIONS:**

You can install with npm:

```
$ npm install -g node-gyp
```

You will also need to install:

> On Unix:
>
> - python (v2.7 recommended, v3.x.x is not supported)
> - make A proper C/C++ compiler toolchain, like GCC
>
> On Windows:
>
> - Python (v2.7.3 recommended, v3.x.x is not supported)
> - Windows XP/Vista/7: Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010 (Express version
>     works well)
> - For 64-bit builds of node and native modules you will also need the Windows > 7 
>     64-bit SDK
> - If the install fails,
>
>   - try uninstalling any C++ 2010 x64&x86 Redistributable that you have
>       installed first.
>   - If you get errors that the 64-bit compilers are not installed you may
>       also need the compiler update for the Windows SDK 7.1
>
> Windows 7/8:
>
> - Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2012/13 for Windows Desktop (Express
>     version works well)
> - If you have multiple Python versions installed,
>     you can identify which Python version node-gyp uses by setting the
>     '--python' variable:

```
$ node-gyp --python /path/to/python2.7
```

> If node-gyp is called by way of npm and you have multiple versions of
>   Python installed, then you can set npm's 'python' config key to the
>   appropriate value:

```
$ npm config set python /path/to/executable/python2.7
```

Comment: ok. I did not click on that to find out. Rather I found this on a separate thread so thought to share it with every link that I have visited in search.

Comment: it would be very appreciated if you give the details of your findings. Giving just links is discouraged in SO. If you find more information and the given answers did not worked in your case.. that information would be appreciated.

Comment: Sure Anurag. will keep this in mind next time I answer any question in SO. Thanks for the tip. =)

Answer (score 3):

This can be fixed by installing all the required tools and configurations using Microsoft's [windows-build-tools](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools) using `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` from an elevated cmd (run as administrator).

Comment: Tried the above comment, and still had the same error.