# npm update fails on Windows 7: Error: Cannot find module 'tar' - partially resolved

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to get my app pulled from github work on Windows 7.

Node and npm installed, I'm getting the following error when trying to npm update in the app folder:

```
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'tar'
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
npm ERR!     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
npm ERR!     at require (module.js:380:17)
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib
\utils\tar.js:13:11)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
npm ERR!     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "update"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\olga\Documents\GitHub\SlumSpy
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\olga\Documents\GitHub\SlumSpy\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I've seen some relevant threads including ones on github, but so far nothing helps. Any ideas?

Yes, i've checked the MS Visual C compiler related issues, I have  .Net and C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 is added to PATH, the compiler inside is MSBuild.exe. Could it be that Node needs an earlier version like VCBuild?

**UPDATE**
I've installed Visual Studio Express 2013 and reinstalled node- the issue changed to  error MSB4019 ... : imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V11
0\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" not found bla-bla-bla. Finally, as in this [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774929/npm-install-g-karma-error-msb4019-the-imported-project-c-microsoft-cpp-defau) , running the same npm command with flag --msvs_version=2013 did the trick!

So I guess many other issues of the kind can be cured in the same way.

Comment: How did you install node and npm?

Comment: http://www.nodejs.org/download/ msi installer for WIN64, and npm goes with it.