# gyp error installing karma

Tags: npm, karma-runner

First time asking a question, sorry if I mess it up. 
I am trying to install karma, I would prefer a local install but can't get it to install globally or locally. Strangely enough karma and karma-cli seem to install however they won't run no matter what I try.

```
 C:\Users\rdana\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\
socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io- 
client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil>
if not defined npm_config_node_gyp 
(node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  
 else (node  rebuild )
 Building the projects in this solution one at a time. 
To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.

  C:\Users\rdana\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\
  node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-        
 client\node_modules\engine.io-  
  client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcxproj(20,3):
  error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was 
  not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct,and that the file   exists on disk.
  gyp ERR! build error
  gyp ERR! stack Error: 
  `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
 gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
 gyp ERR! stack at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm
\\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\rdana\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.2.1
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.2.1
```

I have consulted other posts with this error
[npm install -g karma error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774929/npm-install-g-karma-error-msb4019-the-imported-project-c-microsoft-cpp-defau)

I have tried "npm install -g karma --msvs_version=2013"

I have Visual Studio 2012 on my machine, I have Python 2.7.3 as well.I have uninstalled and reinstalled node-gyp. I haven't messed with any of the Windows SDK, then VS SP1, then a VC++ compiler stuff yet because this is a work machine and I don't have local admin rights to download software.
At this point I am kind of stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

As mentioned before,I have also installed the CLI tool for karma. I have added npm/node to my path. Maybe the reason karma won't run is some executable issues I saw in some posts floating around but I figured I would post on here because of the install issues first.

Thanks again in advance!

Comment: Figured this out with some help, turns out it was a Path issue. Probably isolated to my machine and some configuration setttings. Thanks!

Comment: Having a similar issue, what was the Path issue and resolution?

Comment: @GraehamF hey, it ended up being an issue with the executable not being added to my path. I am still not sure if it was because of path bloat, still can't run karma in my cmd prompt.
I run powershell in my cmd prompt then run karma through there. 
I resolved it by adding karma into my powershell path, the manually mapped in "karma start". 
comment too long, adding another one

Comment: @GraehamF

check out this link for adding something to a powershell path
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-path-variable
 this link for mapping the executable
http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/running-executables-powershell
best of luck!