# How do I resolve the npm MS build issues

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, npm, node-gyp

When I try to do a npm install, I get the following error:

"error MSB4019: The imported project "D:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk."

How do I resolve it?

I tried uninstalling VS 2015 completely and have added MS build tools 2013, still I get the above error :(

Answer (score 2):

As administrator, try installing the windows build tools:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46657986/5204870):

> I got the MSB4019 error because I did not have write permissions on C.
>
> Executing the command with admin privileges helped in my case, but
>   changing read/write permissions on C for your Windows user account
>   should also work.

Other options are listed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18774929/5204870#answers).