# The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found

Tags: npm, node-sass

When trying to `npm install node-sass` on a new virtual machine I'm getting this error:

> `The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found.`

I've tried multiple solutions as follows:

- Installing the VS Build Tools
- installing either LTS, or Current Node.js version.
- Adding/Setting the `VCTargetsPath` variable in the registry.
- Looking for the `MSBuild` folder *(which I don't seem to have)*

Yet nothing's worked.

The odd thing is that my old computer can install and run `node-sass` just fine without having that variable or folder either, so I'm not sure what exactly is the cause of this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a cpp user first of all. But I have got some links that might help.
[npm install -g karma error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774929/npm-install-g-karma-error-msb4019-the-imported-project-c-microsoft-cpp-defau)

Secondly, you can try looking for the MSBuild folder in this location, as it was in mine.
Location: C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120.

Hope it helps :D

Comment: This solved for me, for 2017 version respectively. It is worth noting that setting the version via npm config did NOT work, you have to call it as one command like in the answer linked.