# Python and Visual Studio needed to install a Node.js module (Superfeedr Node.js wrapper)

Tags: javascript, node.js, rss, feed, superfeedr

I try to install a module to interract with Superfeedr's XMPP API in the Node.js. As explained here (https://github.com/superfeedr/superfeedr-node), this is what I do in Node.js:

```
npm install superfeedr
```

But I get the following messages in the console:

```
// at the beginning it seems ok but then...

C:\Users\Gabrielle\node_modules\superfeedr\node_modules\node-xmpp\node_modules\node-xmpp-core\node_modules\node-stringprep>node 
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:101:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:64:11
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.0.6001
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-
gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd 

//and much following...
```

Am I missing something? Why is Python mentioned (I don't use Python at all)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the beginning of the solution: I downloaded Python 2.7
in C:\Python27
and then set the PYTHON variable in Node.js by doing:

```
set PYTHON=C:\Python27\Python.exe
```

(for details see [Running Python on Windows for Node.js dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126050/running-python-on-windows-for-node-js-dependencies))

and then relaunched:

```
npm install superfeedr
```

The error "gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable" does not happen anymore. Good!

But an error message now tells that "Impossible to load the composant Visual C++ "VCBuild.exe"". It asks me: to install development kit Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 2.0 3.5, or to install Visual Studio 2008. Then I got the message asking me: to install development kit .NET Framework 2.0 SDK or to install Visual Studio 2005. Which is another problem, I guess...

(see [error MSB3411: Could not l oad the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608928/error-msb3411-could-not-l-oad-the-visual-c-component-vcbuild-exe))