# Is there a way to install karma without Visual Studio in Windows 8?

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, jasmine-node

I am trying to install karma on Windows 8 using node but I am getting:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB3411: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". ...
```

And I am learning this is becuase Visual Studio is expected??
[error MSB3411: Could not l oad the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608928/error-msb3411-could-not-l-oad-the-visual-c-component-vcbuild-exe)

Is there a way to install karma without Visual Studio?  I just wan to run jasmine tests for the angular tutorial.

SIDE NOTE: Visual Studio Express is free so that is an option

Comment: maybe c++ runtime is enough? http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=5555

Comment: It seemed to but still has teh error.  I guess the failed component wasnt required?  Anyway, your link led me to karma actually installing so thank you!