# npm install canvas: error MSB4019

Tags: node.js, canvas, cmd, npm, cairo

I’m trying to install a node package for a project I have build. When I tell the node-package-manager to install *canvas*, the command prompt shows me the error in the screen shot below.

[image]

I’ve spent a week trying to figure this out. In most places online, they advise the installation of Visual Studio C++ and Cairo. I've done both by installing Visual Studios express edition and copied the contents of Cairo into a GTK folder.

I've also installed node-gyp and updated it, but I am still given this same response from the command prompt.

I also tried using this code `npm install --msvs_version=2013` and this code `npm install canvas --msvs_version=2013`

Is there something I am missing out?

Thanks

Comment: [This problem is resolved in another discussion. Please take look at this discussion ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608928/error-msb3411-could-not-l-oad-the-visual-c-component-vcbuild-exe/18779641#18779641