# Can't install module node.js

Tags: node.js, msbuild

I'm trying to install a module from npm to use in my project. Altough, everytime I try, I get this message:

```
MSBUILD : error MSB3411: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 If the component is not installed, either 1) install the Microsoft Windows SDK
 for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5, or 2) install Microsoft Visual
 Studio 2008.  [C:\Users\<name>\Desktop\max-node\control\node_modules\xbox-cont
roller\node_modules\node-hid\build\binding.sln]
```

I've tried downloading the .NET framework and installing it several times and nothing happens, I've already got the SDK installed.

How do I fix it?

Thanks

- Mackan

Answer (score 0):

The module you're trying to install (node-hid) uses a binary library requiring compilation for your architecture. From the error message, it appears that MSBUILD cannot locate VCBuild.exe which is probably caused by a missing directory in your PATH environment variable. To set things up correctly, you'll need to

1. add the location of VCBuild.exe to your PATH environment variable.
2. npm install -g node-gyp

This will reinstall the [node-gyp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) native extension compiler which, once you add the location of VCBuild.exe to your path, should be able to install any npm module.

See [node-gyp](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) for more information.

Also see [error MSB3411: Could not l oad the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608928/error-msb3411-could-not-l-oad-the-visual-c-component-vcbuild-exe)

Comment: I don't want to install visual studio.

Comment: I guess I'm going to have to even though I don't have enough hard drive space -.-, oh wait, It's impossible to find a download for VS2010

Answer (score 0):

Download Visual Studio Express from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx), then simply run the following command:

`npm config --global set msvs_version 2015` (assuming you've download VSE 2015)

If you have any further issues, make sure your PATH environment variable includes the location of VCBuild.exe (as described in the previous answer).